# Installation and Configuration of MOSS 2007, Identity Not Mapped Exception

Tags: exception, installation, sharepoint-2007

I am trying to install MOSS 2007. This computer already had MOSS2007 installed, we had to uninstall MOSS2007 and install it again (for various reasons).

When we install MOSS2007, the installation completed fine but the Sharepoint Products and Technologies Configuration Wizard runs into the following problem in Step 2.

Why does it not work? What is the root cause/solution?

PS: I have SQL Server 2005 already installed on the machine.

The error message is as follows -

> Failed to create the configuration database
>
> An exception of type System.Security.Principal.IdentityNotMappedException was thrown. Additional exception information: Some or all identity references could not be translated.

The eventviewer has the stack trace -

> Failed to create the configuration
> database. An exception of type
> System.Security.Principal.IdentityNotMappedException
> was thrown.  Additional exception
> information: Some or all identity
> references could not be translated.
> System.Security.Principal.IdentityNotMappedException:
> Some or all identity references could
> not be translated.    at
> System.Security.Principal.NTAccount.Translate(IdentityReferenceCollection
> sourceAccounts, Type targetType,
> Boolean forceSuccess)    at
> System.Security.Principal.NTAccount.Translate(Type
> targetType)    at
> Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPProcessIdentity.GetCurrentSecurityIdentifier()
> at
> Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPProcessIdentity.GetCurrentSid()
> at
> Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPProcessIdentity.Update()
> at
> Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPApplicationPool.Update()
> at
> Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPWebApplication.CreateDefaultInstance(SPWebService
> service, Guid id, String
> applicationPoolId, IdentityType
> identityType, String
> applicationPoolUsername, SecureString
> applicationPoolPassword, String
> iisServerComment, Boolean
> secureSocketsLayer, String
> iisHostHeader, Int32 iisPort, Boolean
> iisAllowAnonymous, DirectoryInfo
> iisRootDirectory, Uri defaultZoneUri,
> Boolean iisEnsureNTLM, Boolean
> createDatabase, String databaseServer,
> String databaseName, String
> databaseUsername, String
> databasePassword,
> SPSearchServiceInstance
> searchServiceInstance, Boolean
> isPaired, Boolean
> autoActivateFeatures)    at
> Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPAdministrationWebApplication.CreateDefaultInstance(SqlConnectionStringBuilder
> administrationContentDatabase,
> SPWebService adminService,
> IdentityType identityType, String
> farmUser, SecureString farmPassword)
> at
> Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPFarm.CreateAdministrationWebService(SqlConnectionStringBuilder
> administrationContentDatabase,
> IdentityType identityType, String
> farmUser, SecureString farmPassword)
> at
> Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPFarm.CreateBasicServices(SqlConnectionStringBuilder
> administrationContentDatabase,
> IdentityType identityType, String
> farmUser, SecureString farmPassword)
> at
> Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPFarm.Create(SqlConnectionStringBuilder
> configurationDatabase,
> SqlConnectionStringBuilder
> administrationContentDatabase,
> IdentityType identityType, String
> farmUser, SecureString farmPassword)
> at
> Microsoft.SharePoint.PostSetupConfiguration.ConfigurationDatabaseTask.CreateOrConnectConfigDb()
> at
> Microsoft.SharePoint.PostSetupConfiguration.ConfigurationDatabaseTask.Run()
> at
> Microsoft.SharePoint.PostSetupConfiguration.TaskThread.ExecuteTask()

Answer (score 0):

You must delete the config database in SQl. But also make sure you delete the previous central admin site in IIS and delete the related app pool.